# In gitlab ci pipeline, how can I connect to redis service using python?

Tags: python, redis, gitlab-ci

My gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

```
stage: functional_test
  only:
    - develop
    - master
    - merge_requests
  services:
    - redis:latest
    - docker:18.06.2-dind
  variables:
    PHOTON_ENV: development
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375
    REDIS_HOST: redis
    REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/0
```

And my python code to connect redis looks like this:

```
self._redis = redis.Redis(host=_host,
                          port=_port,
                          db=_db,
                          decode_responses=True)

_host = 'redis'
_port = 6379
_db = 0
```

However, every time I try this code, this error will show up:

```
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 772, in execute_command
403     connection = pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
404   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 994, in get_connection
405     connection.connect()
406   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 497, in connect
407     raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
408 redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to redis:6379. Name or service not known.
```

Comment: Are you gitlab runner? Shell or docker executor?

Comment: Mine is shell runner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am putting here a solution if anyone else has the same problem.

The redis service in gitlab-ci.yml works as follows:

1. Gitlab runner starts the redis-server in the user image.
2. The redis server can only be connected by the ip-address of your container(the first one, not docker assigned).
3. Pass the ip-address mentioned above to python code(replace "redis" with "$ip")

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to connect to the redis instance from within a nested docker container (dind), here's how I was able to achieve that:

.gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
build-and-test:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
    - redis:latest
  script:
    - docker build -t my_image .
      # Let's get the IP for redis service
      # We need that in order to add as a host available in our container
    - REDIS_IP=$(cat /etc/hosts | awk '{if ($2 == "redis") print $1;}')
      # Just checking that the IP is reachable from outside the container
    - ping -w 2 $REDIS_IP
      # Now we add/map our redis service IP inside the container
    - docker run -t --rm --add-host="redis:$REDIS_IP" my_image python manage.py test
```

Basically; we just have to let the nested docker container know where to find our redis host.
This approach was adapted from: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-selenium-server/-/issues/1#note_216584981

Answer (score 0):

Going from comments and according to [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/redis.html) you have to manually install redis on your gitlab runner server if you are using a shell executor.

Comment: @EasonGao please upvote and accept the answer if it worked for you

Comment: My problem still exists. The documentation merely helps. :-(

Comment: Do you have redis on running on your server?